# when a module imports itself what happens to the global variables

Tags: python, import, module, scope, global

I have the following module:

thismod.py

```
var = 99

def local():
    var = 0  # Change local var

def glob1():
    global var  # Declare global (normal)
    var += 1  # Change global var                             var = 100

def glob2():
    var = 0  # Change local var
    import thismod  # Import myself
    thismod.var += 1  # Change global var

def glob3():
    var = 0  # Change local var
    import sys  # Import system table
    glob = sys.modules['thismod']  # Get module object (or use __name__)    
    glob.var += 1  # Change global var

def test():
    print(var)
    local(); glob1(); glob2(); glob3()
    print(var)
```

driver.py

```
import thismod
thismod.test()
```

my question is in glob2, so glob1 clearly changes var to 100. When the module imports itself in glob2, does it not get a fresh copy of the global variable "var"? I dont understand how **thismod.var +=1 ** changes the original "var".

Answer (score 2):

> When the module imports itself in glob2, does it not get a fresh copy of the global variable "var"?

Nope. When `import foo` is executed, if `foo` has already been imported previously what happens is that the existing reference is used instead.

```
import sys

import foo
print foo is sys.modules['foo']
oldfoo = foo

import foo    
print foo is sys.modules['foo']
print foo is oldfoo
```

Comment: Not if you've run `thismod.py` directly. But if it's being imported from another script, yes.